# Apply animations in CSS on SVG upon button click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

Supposing I have an SVG file `static.svg`:

```
<svg class="machine-svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="200 173 1784 1444" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs>
    <rect id="path-1" x="0" y="16" width="118" height="63"></rect>
    <mask id="mask-2" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="118" height="63" fill="white">
        <use xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
    </mask>
    . . . more elements here (my SVG file is so long I can't possibly paste it here) 
</svg>
```

and another CSS `animation.css` file that contains the animations of the said SVG.

```
.machine-svg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: -12px ) {
  .figure { transform: translate3D(40%, 50px, 0); }
}

@keyframes fall {
  100% { background-position: 0 300px;
  }
}

.shoes {
  transform: translateY(838px) translateX(550px);
  animation: shoes 4s 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 15s;
}

@keyframes shoes {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(838px) translateX(550px) scaleY(1.00) scaleX(1.00);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(838px) translateX(957px) scaleY(1.00) scaleX(1.00);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translateY(838px) translateX(957px) scaleY(0.0) scaleX(0.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(838px) translateX(957px) scaleY(0.0) scaleX(0.0);
  }

}
. . . . . more animation here (also too long)
```

In a page, the SVG must first be static, that means no animations.

So the use case must be, when I click on a button on the page, the SVG starts to animate: to which the animations are on the said CSS file.

Is it possible in Javascript/React to load the CSS animations on that file on the click event of the button?

This was one of my attempt. I tried importing the above CSS (which I converted into SCSS) into a class in another SCSS file.

```
import-svg {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  object-fit: cover;

  &--animate {
    @extend .import-svg;
    @import "animation";  //the animation.css above which I made animation.scss
  }
}
```

(The code below is just a mockup and synthesized, the real code is much more complex)

```
import React from 'react';
import image from 'images/static.svg'; // The SVG file

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: []};
    }
    upload() {
        this.setState({ . . adding contents to items here . . });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <img className={"import-svg" + 
                 (this.state.items !== 'undefined' && this.state.items.length > 0 ?
                 "--animate" : "")} // The class that contains the imported animation.scss file
                 src={image}></img>
            <button onClick={this.upload.bind(this)}>Upload</button>
        )
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work (obviously). But the whole gist of what I want to do is similar to this. Any ideas on how to rework this?

I'm also open to any alternatives, but re-coding the CSS animations into JavaScript shall be the last resort because it takes time (due to the length of code) and I don't have much time available.

(I also have one attempt where I turned the CSS code into a React inline style and the SVG, rendered under a React component `SVGComponent`. But I'm clueless on how to proceed from there)

PS. jQuery is not allowed as per request by the client.

Comment: It should just be a matter of adding the class containing the animations (ie. "shoes") to the appropriate element when you click the button.  Have you tried that?